# HTML symbol brakes height of text

Tags: html, css, symbols

Apparently I am doing something wrong - when I'm trying to put HTML symbol before word, the height of next word, without HTML symbol, has different height, and it's not in the same line.

[image: broken text]

Comment: Please add  the code relevant to this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2gb33gdn/

Comment: in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the default size of the `symbol`. If you set the size of the symbol, you won't see the problem. Have a look at the code below:

```css
.a {
    display: flex;
}
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
span.symbol {
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <h1><span class="symbol">&#9785;</span>123-456-789</h1>
    <h1>text 2017</h1>
</div>
```

In short:

Wrap the symbol inside a `span` and set it's font size.

```
span.symbol {
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="a"><h1>&#9785;123-456-789text 2017</h1>
```

try this , i think it will work